# Close a program when internetconnection lost

Tags: batch-file

i need a command that close a program when internet connection is lost.
i have already this for the startup.

```
@Echo off
:Start
putty.exe -load "test"
ping -n 10 localhost

goto Start
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
start calc
:loop
ping -n 1 google.com >nul && goto:loop || taskkill /im calc.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    rem start program 
    start calc.exe

:loop
    rem test internet connection
    ping -n 1 www.google.com | find "TTL=" 
    if not errorlevel 1 goto loop
    rem connection lost. kill.
    taskkill /fi "imagename eq calc.exe"
```